# eclipse symfony debugger errors in appdevdebugprojectcontainer.xml

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, eclipse-pdt

Using Eclipse Luna with Symfony2. Installed the PDT extensions and was able to get a symfony project up and running. However, the file 
appdevdebugprojectcontainer.xml shows me some errors. This has not interfered with the running of the project but I am still curious to know what this is about.

The first error is in the configurator.

```
cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'configurator' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
```

The other error:

```
<factory class="Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation" method="createValidatorBuilder"/>
```

Error Message

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'factory'. One of '{"http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":file, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":argument, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":configurator, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":call, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":tag, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":property}' is expected.
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem from WTP XML validator. How to ignore:

1. Open project properties (right click on project, properties)
2. On tab Validation, enable project specific settings
3. In XML Schema and XML DTD validator click settings
4. Add Exclude group
5. Select new group and add rule
6. Ignore all *.xml files
7. Save and be happy ;)

I plan to auto create rules these rules in future Symfony Plugin version

Comment: Thanks. Clicked on project->properties-> validation. Enabled project specific settings. Clicked on the settings button next to XML Validator. Clicked on Add Rule and ignored all XML file via the extension method. Works

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the WTP XML validator? The schema at `symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd` defines `configurator` as an empty element, whereas the XML element has content, so the validator is perfectly correct in flagging this as an error. Wouldn't it be better to fix the schema (assuming the xml doc is correct) rather than disable schema validation across the entire project?